# 'Notice: Undefined index' error on plugins page

Tags: plugins, errors

I am using 4.2.4 with Rhythm theme (from themeforest).
Until today, it was OK, now suddenly I am getting the following error on the plugins page in admin:

```
Notice: Undefined index: plugin in D:\Domains\domain.com\wwwroot\wp-admin\includes\update.php on line 281
```

Also, not sure if related, but my portfolio page is also not showing any of the posts.

I have disabled or deleted any of the plugins I installed today (debug, duplicate post, w3 total cache), but no change.

I also activated debug in the config file.

Comment: Try switching to another theme (like Twenty Fifteen) to see if the error goes away. That will help you figure out if there's a problem with that theme.

Comment: Thank you - i activated 2015 and it did not help. It turned out to be one of the plugins that needed an update. It gave an error when i tried  to disable it, but i uploaded a new version via FTP and the error went away.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be one of the plugins that needed an update. It gave an error when i tried to disable it manually on the plugins section, but i uploaded a new version via FTP, the error went away.